# Issue with POST method in Express / Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, post, http-post

I'm working on a small API project using Node and Express. I have a login system using passport and that part is working fine. However, I want the user to be able to enter information into a form which will then be used, by the API, to look up information. The problem that I have is when I hit the submit button, and the POST method fires, calling the action, I get an error of the following: user is not defined. I cannot for the life of me understand what is happening and I think there is an aspect of Node/Express that I'm not understanding when I call the POST method. (I've built a few projects with Node/Express and slowly building bigger things.) Anyways, here is my code:

home.ejs file:

```
<% include partials/header %>

<form method='POST' action='/home'>
   <input placeholder='firstname'>
   <input placeholder='lastname'>
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is the code in the 'controller' folder:

```
const request = require('request');

//Home Route 
module.exports.home = (req,res) => {
    let errors = null;
    res.render('home', {
       errors: errors
    });
 }

 //Home Route for posts
 module.exports.homePost = (req, res) => {
     let errors = null;
     res.render('homePost', {
        errors: errors
      })
  }
```

My Header.ejs file:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
<ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
  <% if (user) { %>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/logout">Logout<span class="sr-only">
     (current)</span></a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/test">Test<span class="sr-only">(current)
     </span></a>
    </li>
  <% } else { %>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="/signup">Sign Up</a>
    </li>
  <% } %>
</ul>
```

Finally, part of my app.js file:

```
app.get('/home', ensureAuthenticated, ctrlMain.home); //This gets the home page just fine.
app.post('/home', ensureAuthenticated, ctrlMain.homePost); //The problem seems to be coming from here-when I execute the POST Method. 

//Access Control
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
   if(req.isAuthenticated()){
      return next();
   }else {
     req.flash('danger', 'Please Login');
     res.redirect('/')
   }
 }
```

The user login system works fine-just don't understand why the post method, on the form, does not work. I believe that I'm missing something basic here. Any help will be great!

I'll also add the passport.js file-where user basically comes from:

```
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
const User = require('../models/user');
const config = require('../config/database');
const bcrypt =require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');

module.exports = function(passport){

//Local Strategy
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){

//Match User name
let query = { username:username };

User.findOne(query, function(err, user){
  if (err) throw err;
  if (!user){
    return done(null, false, {message: 'No user found'});
  }

  //Match Password
  bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, isMatch){
    if(err) throw err;
    if (isMatch){
      return done(null, user);
    }else{
      return done(null, false, {message: 'Wrong Password!!'});
     }
    });
   });
  }));
 }

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
   done(err, user);
  });
 });
```

Comment: where is error server or client?

Comment: Error is on the client side, I believe. Although, maybe the fact that I did not include the user model may be in issue-although I doubt that since I did not need it for getting the home page. Furthermore, I set up a test page, just to see if I had an issue with the server. When I clicked to go to the test page everything was fine. It's as if when I hit the button on the form, the code 'forgets' the user session

Comment: could this be something with a `passport` `user`? is it tied to `/home` somehow?

Comment: should `<button>Submit</button>` be `<button type="submit">Submit</button>`? just a thought...looks like this in your headers might be where the error is coming from...where it is undefined `<% if (user) { %>` where do you define `user`?

Comment: The user would come from the passport.js file which I've added above. I don't believe it is tied to /home because I created a new page, just to test that out, and it works fine. Only crashes when I hit the submit button like something with the Post Method is crashing it/messing with the session somehow. I also tried to add type='submit' and no luck.